# Vue pass slot template to extended component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is any way to pass a template to extended component? Example, that illustrates the problem:

There is a component named `Slide` with a template like so:

```
<template>
    <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-one">
        <div class="swiper-filter"></div>
        <slot />
    </div>
</template>
```

In other place i need to create and mount that component in imperative style:

```
import SlideComponent from '@/components/Slide'
const Slide = Vue.extend(SlideComponent);
new Slide().$mount('#container');
```

The problem is that i have no idea how to pass a template that will be compiled in the slot of the extended component.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f9d8mn9r/)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Vue.compile](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-compile) combined with `$createElement`.

```
const slotTemplate = `<div><h4>This is the slot content</h4>{{message}}</div>`;
const renderer = Vue.compile(slotTemplate)
const slotContent = {
  data(){
    return {
      message: "some data in the slot"
    }
  },
  render: renderer.render,
  staticRenderFns: renderer.staticRenderFns
}

const instance = new Slide();
instance.$slots.default = [instance.$createElement(slotContent)];
instance.$mount("#container");
```

Above is an example of a slot that requires some data. If your slot content is just HTML you could get away with just this:

```
const slotTemplate = `<div><h4>This is the slot content</h4></div>`
const instance = new Slide();
instance.$slots.default = [instance.$createElement(Vue.compile(slotTemplate))];
instance.$mount("#container");
```

Here is an [example](http://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/Mpqpej?editors=1010).

**Note:** [$slots[key] should be an array of vNodes](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-slots). It will render correctly if you use a vNode, but there will be bugs (e.g. when calling vm._update)

Comment: @Edd Your edit was rejected, but I added it to the answer. You are correct.

Comment: Keep in mind that the child component (if any) won't be available until the next tick. If you simplify this into a mixin or method, you can return a promise to expose the created child component.

Comment: what if someone wanna change slot content? ```vm.$slots.default = [ ]``` and ```vm.$slots.default.push(somevnode)``` seems to be useless?

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to change your approach a little bit, a `<component>` instead of `<slot>`:

https://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/z5Lgbjv8/

```
const Parent = {
  template: `<div>
        <span>parent content</span>
      <component :is="view"></component>
    </div>`,
  data() {
    return { view: '' }
  }
}

const Other = {
  template: `<div>
        <h1>from Other</h1>
    </div>`
}

const Slide = Vue.extend(Parent)

// how to pass template to the Parent`s slot?
new Slide({
  data: { view: Other }
}).$mount('#container')
```

Answer (score 1):

*(This question is similar to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50150668/how-to-create-vue-js-slot-programatically). I am just gonna share a similar answer I post for that question here.)*

The trick is simple. Basically, when extending, create a new component that registers `Parent` as a local component.

**Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jacobgoh101/omjgmb3f/**

```
const Slide = Vue.extend({
  components: {
    Parent
  },
  template: `
  <Parent>
    <div style="color:red">I am a slot</div>
  </Parent>
`
});
new Slide().$mount('#container')
```

Answer (score 0):

If You can change Your source code structure,
You should also be able to use jsx.
In Vue-Cli3 it requires additional babel plugin, in Nuxt it works out of the box).
You simply create some hook function as method or compute, for example:

```
slotHook () {
  return(
  <template v-slot.../>
)}
```

and place it inside the render function.
Then, in the child (component extending the default one), You overwrite the slotHook method:

```
slotHook () {
  return (
    <template v-slot... some-differen-params:.../>
)}
```

This approach does not cause any errors/issues during render and works flawless.
Other approach  might be to use PUG templates and their block & extend functionality.
I know I'm posting this response quite late, but maybe it could help somebody.

Answer (score -2):

You have to pass it like this:

```
<Slide>
   //HTML code here goes to slot
</Slide>
```

Comment: i have no control over the template of the place where i need to mount the component. So the question is how to pass slot data from the code...

Comment: Can you explain what you are looking exactly ?